# We'd like to fetch Instagram Stories that a business account is tagged in

Tags: facebook, instagram-graph-api

According to this - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/instagram_manage_comments/ - one of the allowed usages of instagram_manage_comments is "Your app can also read and respond to public media and comments that a business has been photo tagged or @mentioned in, including Stories". I also confirmed with Meta app review team that this permission should indeed enable us to fetch tagged Stories. The exact quote from them is: "The instagram_manage_comments permissions allows you to fetch the stories that you are tagged by other users"

The problem is we are unable to get any webhook notification when a tagged story is created. So how do we get this data otherwise? The one workaround is we had access to instagram_manage_messages permission but we don't have that.

Has anyone successfully tried to solve this problem?